# 2 button OnClick event on Popup Window in Android

Tags: android

I have 2 buttons in my xml file, onclicklistener open new popup.why this eror? can help me??

My Java code is as follows:

```
Public class Bab1_b1a extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;
    private Button hans, logemann;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bab1_b1a);

        hans = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hans);
        logemann = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logemann);

        hans.setOnClickListener(myhandler1);
        logemann.setOnClickListener(myhandler2);

    }

    View.OnClickListener myhandler1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_popup_hans);
            dialog.setTitle("Hans Kelsen");

            TextView text1 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            text1.setText("Negara ialah");

            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.hans_kelsen);

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.back_hans);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener myhandler2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_logemann);
            dialog.setTitle("Logemann");`enter code here`
            TextView text1 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            text1.setText("Negara ialah.");

            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.logemann);

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.back_logemann);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    };
};
```

xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Bab1_b1a" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_back"
        android:contentDescription="@string/skx" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/h_neg"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hans"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hans_kelsen"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/logemann"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/logemann" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_forw"
        android:contentDescription="@string/skx" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone help me know the reason for this problem and how do I solve it. I am a newbie to Android.

Thanks

Comment: i dont know,, but its force close if i open this activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button bt_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
    bt_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_popup);
            dialog.setTitle("Hans Kelsen");

            //Her add your textView and ImageView if you want

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bt1_popUP);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
        });

         // Same thing for bt_2

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }

}
```

Your Main Activity XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BT 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/bt1"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="BT 2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Your POP-UP XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#FFF123"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt1_popUP"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Close" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

enjoy :)